# WineSkin with .NET Application

Tags: .net, winforms, macos, wine

I have a .net application which now works perfectly when i have installed .net 4 on my Wine instance (Mac OS X).

Now my challenge is to wrap the Instance and give it to the customer. the easiest way to do this is by creating a Wineskin instance and running all the required tricks and attaching the executables with that instance.

As redistributing .Net framework files in installed state is illegal (instead we need to provide the setup.exe and run the setup in silent mode, after showing an agreement).

Is there any way to call the Wintricks on first run,

As a first try i made a small Delphi exe and checked for .net installation, if there is no any .net framework the delphi app will launch the .net installer which is bundled with the binaries.

When launching the .net installer i am getting following error. (it works perfectly with winetricks)

[image]

commandline used to launch .net setup

```
dotnetfx40x86.exe /q
```

Please note my application is not compatible with mono. I have to use pure .Net

Is there any way to call the Wintricks on first run, and let the wine tricks use the bundled installer(instead of downloading again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved the problem in following way.

Even if Wine supports some latest Windows APIs its still under the hood looks like a Windows XP System, So the solution was simple.

Installation of .NET 4.0 requires windows updater components to install on Windows 7, but this is not the case in earlier OSs as the OSs have no idea what .NET framework is.

The Delphi Application which installs .NET silently will be Run under Windows XP compatibility mode, Then only .NET 4.0 can be installed from scratch (NO Windows Update component will be tangled in the Windows XP mode, But in 7 and later .NET is installed as a Windows Update)

Then my .net application will be Run as Windows 7 Application, Since most of the API required in my app is implemented in WINE...